# Terraform one state file per Resource Group

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have multiple resource groups in a subscription. Is it possible to change backendAzureRmKey during run time in order to maintain one tfstate file per resource group using Azure devops? Or it is possible only by having multiple pipelines.

```
- task: TerraformCLI@0
            displayName: 'Terraform Init'
            inputs:
              command: 'init'
              backendType: azurerm
              backendServiceArm: "$(tfazdemo-service-connection)"
              backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: "$(tfazdemo-sa-name)"
              backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: "$(tfazdemo-rg-name)"
              backendAzureRmContainerName: "$(tfazdemo-cont-name)"
              backendAzureRmKey: "$(tfazdemo-sa-key)"
              backendAzureRmSubscriptionId: "$(tf-az-sub-dev)"
              workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/tfStorage/'
```

Comment: This sounds potentially dangerous.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I am new to Terraform, I thought even if there is a misconfiguration in resources then the blast radius will be very low (within resource group).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the same pipeline using multiple Tasks, then in each task specify your key with `backend-config`

Comment: Could you please give more information on this. How to decide which task will execute for a specific RG?